# Upload data in web using cpp

Tags: php, c++, upload

I am using this code for uploading a data in web but here is some error in this code.
here is a code.

```
static TCHAR hdrs[] =
      _T("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
static TCHAR frmdata[] =
      _T("name=John+Doe&userid=hithere&other=P%26Q");
static LPSTR accept[2]={"*/*", NULL};

// for clarity, error-checking has been removed
HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen("MyAgent",
      INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, _T("http://localhost"),
      INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, "POST",
      _T("/upload.php"), NULL, NULL, accept, 0, 1);
HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), frmdata, strlen(frmdata));
// close any valid internet-handles
```

Here is a php code.

```
<?php

 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $userid = $_POST['userid'];
 $other = $_POST['other'];

  $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
  $txt1 = $name."\n";
  fwrite($myfile, $txt1);
  $txt2 = $userid."\n";
  fwrite($myfile, $txt2);
  $txt3 = $other."\n";
  fwrite($myfile, $txt3);
  fclose($myfile);

 ?>
```

When I compile the code it gives error like invalid conversion from char** to const char**. Here is a php file `upload.php` it works well and I connect it with my cpp file for upload data in web.
Can any one help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the project is configured to use Unicode. The proper UNICODE compliant code will look like this:

```
TCHAR hdrs[] = _T("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
TCHAR frmdata[] = _T("name=John+Doe&userid=hithere&other=P%26Q");
LPCTSTR accept[] = {_T("*/*"), NULL};

HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen(_T("MyAgent"), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, _T("http://localhost"), INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, _T("POST"), _T("/upload.php"), NULL, NULL, accept, 0, 1);
HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, _tcslen(hdrs), frmdata, _tcslen(frmdata));
```

Comment: There is a some kind of error like `undefine refrence to internetOpenA@20`

Comment: Switch to UNICODE and link to Wininet.lib

Comment: How to switch to UNICODE ?

Comment: Go to project settings and select Use Unicode Character Set

Comment: I'm using `dev c++` can you tell me step by step

Comment: can I do it in dev C++ ?

Comment: I'm sure you can. Just refer to dev C++ documentation